# check preceding sibling child followingsiblings`

Tags: xslt

I've the below 2 XML cases

**Case1:**

```
<para>
<phrase>21.001</phrase>
 <content-style font-style="italic">Modern wordings.</content-style> The modern 
      form of the hulls clauses goes back to 1982 and those clauses remain in 
      widespread use. The Hulls clauses were revised in a number of significant
</para>
```

**Case2:**

```
<para>
  <phrase>21.146</phrase>
</para>
<para>
   <content-style font-style="bold">14.</content-style> Where the ship has stranded,
     the insurer is liable for the excepted losses, although the loss is not       
     attributable to the stranding, provided that when the stranding takes place the 
     risk has attached and if the policy be on goods, that the damaged goods are 
     on board.
</para>
```

here i'm trying to check if there is `following-sibling to phrase, which is child of para`, but here the condition is `true` for both the cases, where in the condition should be true only for **Case1**. Below is my XSLT.

```
<xsl:template name="para" match="para">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::para/phrase/following-sibling::node())">
    <div>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./@align">
<xsl:attribute name="class">
                            <xsl:text>para align-</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./@align"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>    
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            <xsl:text>para</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>    
                        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
 </div>    
    </xsl:if>
     </xsl:template>
```

please let me know where am i going wrong and how can i fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please include a complete scenario that accurately describes your input and your expected result *in that scenario*. See: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpD

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the following-sibling of phrase, just use

```
phrase/following-sibling::node()
```

And of course, only the nodes which are in the same parent will be selected as your context node is "para"

Comment: Hi @Lingamurthy, Thanks for the response, I want to see the preceding para phrase's following sibling from current para, but not in the same para

Comment: May be you should explain your problem by providing the complete XSLT, and expected output. It will make it easy for us to understand.

Comment: @user2423959 This answer is a literal translation of *"a following-sibling to phrase, which is child of para"*. If that's not what you expect, perhaps you should clarify. Do you really mean *sibling*? Do really you wish to select any *node*?